# Error C2676 binary '<<': 'std::ostream' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I don't understand the compilation error C2676

for the below code

```
#ifndef __VEC_3D_H__
#define __VEC_3D_H__

#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

namespace Internal
{
    /** very simple 3D vector/ point */
    class Vec3D
    {
    public:
        float mX;
        float mY;
        float mZ;

        /// null constructor
        Vec3D(void) {}

        /// construct from data
        Vec3D(float x, float y, float z) : mX(x), mY(y), mZ(z) {}

        inline friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Vec3D& v) 
        {
            os << "(" << v.mX << ", " << v.mY << ", " << v.mZ << ")";
            return os;
        }
    };

}

#endif
```

I have put a functionally identical code in another class and it compiles and runs fine. What is wrong here?

EDIT1: corrected BOBVec3d to Vec3D, was a typo

EDIT2: removed `using namespace Internal;`, it is indeed point-defeating to have it in a header file

Comment: On a tangential note, all identifiers that conrain two underscores in a row, and all identifiers that start with an underscore and a capital letter, are reserved. Defining such identifiers in your own code is UB.

Comment: Putting `using namespace Internal;` in the header kind of defeats the purpose of having a namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

missing `#include <iostream>` at the top.

Fixed it. 
(Oh what terribly terribly poor compilation errors in C++ can be..)

Comment: You may want to check out an extension such as [Resharper for C++](https://www.wholetomato.com/) or [Visual Assist X](https://www.wholetomato.com/), they make trivial mistakes like this almost impossible to make. As a newbie I found it very helpful. :-)

Comment: I installed Visual Assist, and will try it out for a month, but for this question's problem, it didn't help. (I commented the #include <iostream> in the top, saved and compiled it and: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bd3my8l3r7bqcrj/DidntHelp.PNG?raw=1

Comment: I apologize. I actually use Resharper myself, but many people prefer to use VAX (for performance reasons on large projects, although I have had no issues), so thought I'd mention it as well. I checked your code with Resharper and it did seem to pick it up. [Here's a picture.](https://i.imgur.com/HZIyjil.jpg)

Comment: hm :), you mentioned ReSharper, but you linked to wholetomato.com :)
You meant to link to https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/ correct?

Comment: uuh, I installed resharper and I'm confused about that's wrong on my end. What I see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/64verq3shjam969/What.PNG?raw=1
and the top red highlight says: "Precompiled header must be incluided at the top of the source file", and the bottom: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v77svb2aqdzme2a/AABAyZJ6CX5LhcQpqEjajchSa?raw=1
what do you think is missing compared to yours @notanalien?

Comment: Got it, ReShape got confused by #include <vector>
when we delete #include <vector>, we see what you see

Comment: Come one!! The compiler can do better that this error message! I have visual assist installed and it did not help. Shall we file this as an enhancement with Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error

> Error C2676   binary '<<': 'std::ofstream' does not define this operator
>   or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
>   operator  Project2c++ c:\users\dinga\desktop\practice projects for
>   c++\project2c++\project2c++\fruit.h

As a solution 
i just used `#include <fstream> (ie fstream)` in the header file where the class was defined.
this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change **BOBVec3d** to **Vec3D**:

```
BOBVec3D(void) {}
BOBVec3D(float x, float y, float z) : mX(x), mY(y), mZ(z) {}
inline friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const BOBVec3D& v);
```

to

```
Vec3D(void) {}
Vec3D((float x, float y, float z) : mX(x), mY(y), mZ(z) {}
inline friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Vec3D& v);
```

Comment: sorry about that, was anonymizing the code and missed those entries